# Not able to append to selectbox after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I called an AJAX script to fill the data to my selection box, i successfully able to get the values but they are not appending to the selection box.

```
 $('#choose_area').on('change',function(){
                var stateID = $(this).val();
                alert(stateID);
                if(stateID){
                    var xz=$.ajax({
                        type:'post',
                        url:'../processRequest/locationRefine.php?stateID='+stateID,
                        data:{'stID':stateID},
                        success: function(html){
                            $('#choose_loc').append(html);
                            $('#choose_clg').html('<option value="">Please choose Location of College</option>');
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(xz);
                }else{
                    $('#choose_loc').html('<option value="">Please choose state to apply</option>');
                    $('#choose_clg').html('<option value="">Please choose Location of College</option>');
                }
        });

          <div class="input-field col s4">
            <br>
            <label for="area_selection">Choose State Applying for</label>
            <?php
                include '../config/db.php';
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM college_info"; 
                $run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                //$row = mysqli_num_rows($run)
            ?>
            <select id="choose_area">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Your State</option>
            <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                    //extract($row);
                    //print_r ($row);
                    //exit;
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['state'].'</option>';
            ?>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
            <br>
            <label for="location_selection">Choose Location of College</label>
            <select id="choose_loc">
                <option value="">Please Choose Location</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s4">
            <br>
            <label for="college_selection">Choose College to apply</label>
            <select id="choose_clg">
                <option value="">Please Choose College</option>
            </select>
            </div>
```

And again i tried to push to selection value based on query unable to append using $.each function, can anyone tell me what wrong i am doing?

Comment: I can't see any usage of the `$.each` function you mentioned.

Comment: I know here i have not used but in another section it is used, can you guide me with this only.

Comment: Can you explain why you added the if statement if(stateID) and what you want to achieve from that.

Comment: if state id is chosen then ajax call will occur else change the values of rest two fields accordingly.

Comment: why do you think you need .each? What exactly is coming back the "success" function? i.e. what is the value of the `html` variable? If it really is valid HTML then you don't need a loop to append it to the select.

Comment: Getting this value in response
<option value="" disabled>Please select location</option><option value="1">BHUBANESWAR</option>
My php section

 if($run && $rowcnt > 0){
  echo '<option value="" disabled>Please select location</option>';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
   echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['location'].'</option>';

Comment: you should just be able to insert that directly into your `<select>` then, I can't see how it could be causing you a problem, unless you have another error caused by something else.

Comment: Yes i am quite amazed with that, why its not getting appended there.

Comment: have you checked your browser's console for any errors? Populating the select using that HTML string works, by itself - see example here: https://jsfiddle.net/69ekLacs/ . Obviously I couldn't emulate the ajax, but you can see that, if your response does indeed contain that HTML, you should be able to populate the select with it. So my guess is something else is going wrong, or the situation is not actually as you're describing it.

Comment: No errors coming that is the main problem otherwise i could have that by myself. No error in console yet.

Comment: this makes no sense then. Perhaps your `<select>` doesn't exist yet on the page when this is running?? Or you have a typo in the CSS selector? (Doesn't look like it from your example code, but perhaps something is different in the real version?)